# load part of the html view only after ajax is completed - sync

Tags: javascript, ajax, backbone.js, synchronization, marionette

I need to load part of my html template, just after I get the result from templateHelper that using ajax.

In my `ItemView` code:

```
templateHelpers: {
  currentUserCan:  function(action) {
    $.when( currentUser.can(action) ).done(function(permission){
      return permission;
    });
  }
}
```

`can` function:

```
can: function( action ){

 var defer = $.Deferred(),
 params = { .... }

 $.get( config[ 'api' ] , params)
 .done(function(response) {
    defer.resolve(response['permission'])
  })
 .fail(function(response){
    defer.resolve(false) 
  });

  return defer.promise();
}
```

My template:

```
<div class="large-8 columns">
  <p><% if (currentUserCan('some_action')) {  do something, console.log("can") } else { console.log('can not')}%></p>
  <p>Last Status:<%= date %></p>
</div>

<div class="large-8 columns">
...
...
```

Because of the async ajax, I'm getting undefined as result, and 'can not' at console, although it got true.
How can I load my code at the `if` statement, only after the ajax is completed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't try to use asynchronous code in a "synchronous way".

Maybe, it will be a good solution for you:

```
templateHelpers: {
  currentUserCan:  function(action) { return currentUser.can(action); }
}
```

- here we return promise from the function, since we want to react on asynchronous action completion.

`<div class="large-8 columns">
  <p><% $.when(currentUserCan('some_action')).done(function(permission) {
    if(permission)
      console.log("can");
    else
      console.log('can not');
  }) %></p>
  <p>Last Status:<%= date %></p>
</div>`

- here we use promise right from the template.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I didn't know I can use `jquery` in `underscore` templates.

Comment: just because you can use doesn't mean you should. it's really bad practice to heavily use js inside of your template. you should really limit your templates to be that templates that generate html and leave logic like this to your views and controllers.

Comment: But I don't want to load the template only after I get result. It can take time...